# simple Pointer initialization

Tags: c++, pointers

It has been a while that I used pointers and I just wanna quickly check how I can initialize an integer pointer?

```
a) int *tmpPtr = 0;

b) int *tmpPtr = null;

c) int a = 0;
   int *tmpPtr = &a;
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for all your answers so far. The funny thing is, that if I intitalize
the pointer as follows, then the mem::copy operation works fine.

```
int tmp = 0;
int *tmpPtr = &tmp;
Mem::Copy((void*)tmpPtr, basepointer(), sizeof(int));
```

However,  if I do it like this:

```
int *tmpPtr = 0;
Mem::Copy((void*)tmpPtr, basepointer(), sizeof(int));
```

then I get a crash during mem::copy...

Weird!

Comment: You're getting a crash because int *tmpPtr = 0; is a NULL pointer and is not pointing into a memory segment containing an int.  You're basically saying this pointer points at nothing and you can't copy integers that take up memory space into something that has no space.

int *tmpPtr = &tmp;   Is assigning the ADDRESS of the memory occupied by tmp to your pointer.  Here you are saying that your pointer points at the memory allocated to tmp.  Now, Copy can actually copy data into that space because your pointer is pointing at something it can use.

Comment: Yes, that makes then absolut sense! Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 39):

Simple questions are fine, I think it's well established that SO is meant to be for all levels, not just an elite.

There is no `null` in C (unless you define it yourself). Initializing to a null pointer can be done in one of the following two ways:

```
int *p = 0;
int *p = NULL;
```

If you dereference `p` after that, you're likely to get an access violation (I believe it's undefined behavior according to the standard, so really, anything could happen, up to and including, total annihilation of the universe - it may even continue to run fine, but I wouldn't rely on it).

To get a pointer to a real integer, just use:

```
int a = 7;
int *p = &a;
```

using the address-of operator.

Re your edit, it's not weird at all, you just need to visualize it. Let's pretend that all variables are created starting at memory location 100 and integers and pointers are both 4 bytes in length. Breaking your two situations down to their simplest form:

```
                                  int x = 2;
int *px = 0;                      int *px = &x;

         +-----+                          +-----+
px(100): |   0 |                  x(100)  |   2 |
         +-----+                          +-----+
                                  px(104) | 100 |
                                          +-----+
```

Then you execute the command

```
*px = 7;
```

in an attempt to change the variable pointed to by `px`.

On the left-hand side, you will try to write the value 7 to memory location 0. That's a bad thing; very few systems will allow you to do that without crashing, even fewer will allow it without any adverse effects at all (some versions of HP-UX actually worked okay).

On the right side is what *should* happen. The value picked up from `px` is 100, so the value 7 is written to that memory location, changing `x` as intended.

I often find pictures (even primitive ASCII art ones, since I'm no Rubens or Botticelli) help clarify the concepts. Hopefully it's cleared it up a little for you.

Answer (score 6):

Reply to your question in EDIT:

- When you do this :

  ```
  int tmp = 0;
  int *tmpPtr = &tmp;
  Mem::Copy((void*)tmpPtr, basepointer(), sizeof(int));
  ```

tmpPtr is pointing to the address of variable `tmp` and it is in the [stack](http://www.maxi-pedia.com/what+is+heap+and+stack). And notice that the "safe area" pointed by tmpPtr is the size of `tmp` (which is 4 in some machine and 2 in others). If you were to copy more than sizeof(int) bytes to tmpPtr you will risk of  crashing the stack.

- When you do this :

  ```
  int *tmpPtr = 0;
  Mem::Copy((void*)tmpPtr, basepointer(), sizeof(int));
  ```

The value of tmpPtr is 0 ,so you will get a [segment fault.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) ,which is a memory protection mechanism offered by the operation system. For example , you are not allowed to write any [virtual address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address) that is less than 4K.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it any of those ways except it is NULL not null.  I prefer int *p = 0;   over int *p = NULL;

To eliminate some confusion I sense, setting  int *p = 0 or setting MyObject *p = 0; results in the same thing.... a null pointer that will usually crash your program if you attempt to dereference it though technically it's undefined behavior.  The example you have in C is different from the others because you are actually setting the pointer to point at an integer set as 0.

```
int *pNull = 0;
int c = *pNull;  // Undefined behavior.  Most likely crashing your program!

int a     = 0;
int *pInt = &a;

int x = *pInt;   // x equals 0 

a = 10;
int y = *pInt;   // y equals 10
```

Comment: The difference is that for a & b tmpPtr will point to 0/null and for c it will point to the address of a

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your pointers which point to nothing by a null pointer constant. Any constant expressions with value 0 serve as a null pointer constant. In C *NULL* macro is used by convention.

Answer (score 1):

I was just refreshing my pointer knowledge and stumbled across this.

```
int *tmpPtr = 0;
```

i find it easier to think of it like this:

```
int *tmpPtr ;

tmpPtr = 0 ;
```

I 'believe' the above 2 lines are equivalent to that one line.
so basically the address to be de-referenced is set to 0 or `NULL`.

Comment: You should initialize your variable as soon as possible. Your second proposition doesn't initialize your pointer, it only does it later.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `null` keyword in C (at least in ANSI C99). You could use a) or c).

In c) you'll not initialize pointer with null, you'll initialize it with address of local variable.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
int *tmpPtr = 0;
```

initializes the *pointer* value to 0, so tmpPtr is pointing "nowhere"; i.e., not a valid memory location.  You have to assign a valid memory location to the pointer first like you did in the previous snippet.