# What is the cleanest way to initialize pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

I want to have a C function that reads a file and returns a dynamic array of ints. What is the best way to initialize the pointers for this array ?

My current version:

```
void readFile(int* array,int* size){
   // ...read the file and see there are X integers...
   array = malloc(X * sizeof(int));
   *size = X;
   // ... fill the array ...
   }
int main() {
   int* array;
   int size;
   readFile(array,&size);
   //Work with array
   return 0;
}
```

This gives me unitialized warnings, is it ok just to do

```
int* array = NULL
```

or is there a better and cleaner way to achieve this ?

Comment: why don't you use mmap()? Why don't you use pread()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple Pointer initialization question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367363/simple-pointer-initialization-question)

Comment: You need to pass in int **array to readFile(), otherwise you are not returning the address of the malloc()

Comment: @OldProgrammer Well, it works right now with function(int* array)...

Comment: @dAm2K You mean for reading the file ? Lets get away from that, it was just an example. My question rather points at initializing and returning dynamic arrays / pointers.

Comment: "Well, it works right now" — you are grossly mistaken.

Comment: `int` is not the right type for a variable named `size`...

Comment: This is actually one example of when a thoughtless initialization of a pointer with a dummy value of `NULL` disabled a useful diagnostic message from the compiler. I.e. that initialization made it look as if "everything's fine". This is why I'm against that strange guideline that states that one should always initialize all variables, even if one yet has no meaningful value to initialize them with.

Comment: Agreed, and using a variable with a wrong value is no less of a bug than using an uninitialized variable is, regardless of warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Technical comment**

First off, you are having issues because `readFile` takes `int *`, not `int **`. If you had

```
void readFile(int **array, int *size) {
  *array = malloc(X * sizeof(int));
  ...
```

you'd actually be able to call it like in

```
int main() {
  int *array, size;
  readFile(& array, & size);
  ...
```

so the caller's `array` will point to what `readFile` allocated.

**Design question**

To your specific question, technically both is possible, as long as responsibility for initialization/allocation and cleanup are clearly understood:

- `main` allocates the array, and `readFile` fills it.
- `readFile` allocates and fills the array with the contents of your file.

`main` could allocate the memory, because it is the function that will know when to clean up (free the memory). Otherwise, the unit in which `readFile` is implemented could also implement a `freeFile` function for others to use.

Comment: "some may argue that it is preferred for main to allocate the memory" — they may argue, but they won't win the argument.

Comment: This is spot on, except for the bit about main allocating the memory. For simple types (like arrays of int), as long as it's clear who owns the pointer, it doesn't matter.  For complex types, allocation and deallocation should be done through `xxx_new` and `xxx_delete` functions, so it still won't matter; the key is making it clear who actually owns the pointer.

Comment: @s.bandara Thanks for your answers ! I'm not sure how you mean "main allocates the array", because in main i do not know how big the array has to be..

Comment: I think that is why the commenters hinted at `readFile` better being in charge of this rather than the alternative I mentioned. I also made edits to that section. Possibly @n.m. could check?

Comment: @JHnet It's common for file parsing to be split into multiple functions.  You would split the `readFile` function into two functions: (a) one that reads the header info (or does some other magic) and returns the number of ints, and (b) one that reads the ints.  In your case, it's not the most linear design, but it can be useful in some places.  It's worth noting: this approach is often used in code that parses a file into a struct, and each function populates part of the struct.

Comment: Thank you all, i realized all the tips from here !